# Glue working with Pandas, based on the documentation

Tags: pandas, amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I am trying to get Pandas working, based on the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/add-job-python.html#python-shell-supported-library)?

Under the list of Supported Libraries for Python Shell Jobs they mention:

pandas (required to be installed via the python setuptools configuration, setup.py)

I have tried this with a setup file

```
from setuptools import setup
setup(
    name="dependecy_package",
    version="0.1",
    packages=['pandas','shapely','psycopg2','s3fs'],
    package_dir = {'': '/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages'}
)
```

I uploaded this generated egg file and uploaded to S3. I then reference the new ex file as part of the run job settings. I however get this error upon startup

```
ImportError: C extension: No module named 'pandas._libs' not built. 
If you want to import pandas from the source directory, you may need to run 'python setup.py build_ext --inplace --force' to build the C extensions first.
```

How do I fix this?